# How can I use the same prepared statement for different tables in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have quite often some very similar SQL queries I have to submit, e.g. deleting one row in a table where I know the ID. Here is my piece of code with the [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `".MY_FIRST_TABLE."` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `".MY_SECOND_TABLE."` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `:table` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");

$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':table', MY_FIRST_TABLE);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':table', MY_SECOND_TABLE);
$stmt->execute();
```

If I try this, nothing happens. So I used the following snippet to analyze the error:

```
print_r($conn->errorInfo());
var_dump($stmt);
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```

I got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(45) "DELETE FROM `:table` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1"
}
SQL: [45] DELETE FROM `:table` WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1
Params:  2
Key: Name: [3] :id
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":id"
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Name: [6] :table
paramno=-1
name=[6] ":table"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Is something like this possible?

(I am currently using prepared statements only for security reasons, not for performance reasons.)

**Prepared statements and IN-Clause**

I've just read that I can't use prepared statements for table or column names ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304)). So I guess I have to search another solution.

Comment: What happens if you try to run that?

Comment: Nothing. I've added some lines to show give you as much information as I have about this "bug". I think it's intentionally not possible to replace table names as prepared statements seem to get stored in the database for optimization ... as far as I understood. I guess it might be difficult to do this for every table simultaniously. So I hope I'll get an alternative for prepared statements or told that I am wrong with my assumptions about them.

Answer (score 1):

I think (I'm not 100% sure about this) that you are trying to query a table called

```
`'TableName'`
```

Or

```
`"TableName"`
```

depending on how PDO tries to quote your parameters. I've been looking on how not to quote strings in PDO (I had your same problem) but I gave up a long time ago and wrote my own implementation.

Perhaps you could pre-process the queries and substitute a parameter with the table name, being careful on the *gotchas* ([That's what I'm talking about](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) that could happen while substituting the table param name.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I've taken a look at the query which was received by the MySQL-Server: `SELECT user_password FROM 'chess_users' WHERE 1 = '1'`. This seems to be the reason why I can't do it with prepared statements. Another interesting observation: This query was created by `SELECT user_password FROM :table WHERE :uid = :uid`. Why is :uid replaced once by 1 and once by '1'?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, which type of quote did you use when you bound the uid parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "type of quote". I've used this bind statement (once): `$stmt->bindValue(':uid', USER_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);` and USER_ID is `int` before and after the PDO statements. I've checked that with `var_dump`.

Comment: I guess PDO quotes only the first occurrence of the parameter with the type you want, and the second with the default quoting (which is `PDO::PARAM_STR`). I'm now running some test to see if I wrote crap.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach? :

```
# I'm hard-coding the values so just handle that first and set $id1 and $id2
$parameterArray = array('MY_FIRST_TABLE' => $id1, 'MY_SECOND_TABLE' => $id2);
$sql = '';

foreach($parameterArray as $tableNameKey => $idValue) {
    # build sql
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `". $tableNameKey ."` WHERE `id`=". $idValue ." LIMIT 1";

    # prepare and execute
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    # processing code after execution goes here
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Here you just go through a loop using an array of tables and ids from which you want to build your `DELETE` sql statements.. Could you give this a try?